# useEffect clean up function runs in developement and doesn't run in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, vite

I using React.js with electron (vite-electron)

I have a `useEffect` hook with a clean up function that reset some state on unmount, I also have a ref value to prevent the function from executing in the first render (to not reset data once the page renders)

```
const firstUpdate = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
    // prevent the callback from executing on first mount
    if (firstUpdate.current) {
        firstUpdate.current = false;
        return;
    }
    return () => {
        // clean up data
        dispatch(resetTeethData());
        dispatch(resetChartingData());
        dispatch(resetConsultationData());
        dispatch(setDocumentPatient(null));
    };
}, []);
```

It runs perfectly fine in development, but when I build the electron app it doesn't work

PS: The code above it works, but the cleanup function doesn't work when quitting the page (unmount)

I'm expecting it to run some code when unmounting and not in the first render

Comment: There could be a few things causing this. I think you should check if there are any build configurations. Different environments might have different config requirements. Then check the dependencies. Does one environment have different packages/dependencies installed? Based on the provided code, I don't see any reason why the cleanup wouldn't work in all environments. Which makes me think it might have something do do with the build process or package dependencies and versions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was in the ref value, I managed to solve it using a state instead of a ref

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
    // This code will run on component mount
    return () => {
      if (mounted) {
        // This code will only run on component unmount
        // because `mounted` is false when the component is mounted.
        console.log('Component unmounted');
      }
    };
  }, [mounted]);
```

`